# Bind to Count of items in the DataContext

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to bind to the Count/amount of items within my DataContext.

I have an object, let's say person which has a `List<address>` as a property. I would like to display the amount of addresses for that person, i.e.: 5 or 6 or whatever the case may be.

I've tried `{Binding Path=address#.Count}` and a few others but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to bind the name of the property, not its type.

C#:

```
public class Person
{
    ...
    public List<address> Addresses { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
{Binding Addresses.Count}
```

Assuming your `DataContext` is an object of type `Person`.

Comment: I thought that binding to Object.Value causes memory leaks in WPF?

Comment: this does not update UI as the list changes

Answer (score 24):

As tehMick says, you can bind using the path `Addresses.Count`.

Note, however, that unless `Addresses` is an `ObservableCollection<address>`, or some other type that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, adding and removing addresses won't affect the number that appears in the UI after its initial display.  If you need that, you will either need to change the type of the collection in your view model (that's easiest), or implement a property in your view model that exposes the count, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event every time you add or remove an address.

**Edit**

I love reading an answer, thinking, "hey, that's not right," and then realizing I wrote it.

If you bind to an object that *just* implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the count in the UI won't change if items are added or removed ot the collection.  The object *also* has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` when the `Count` property changes.

Which, fortunately, `ObservableCollection<T>` does.  So my answer's not *that* wrong.

Answer (score 4):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CountDemo.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CountDemo" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Addresses.Count}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace CountDemo
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new Person();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public List<Address> Addresses
        {
            get { return new List<Address>() {new Address(), new Address(), new Address()}; }
        }
    }

    public class Address
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [tehMick's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916564/bind-to-count-of-items-in-the-datacontext/2917152#2917152) answer with functional sample code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.Wpf.PropertyCount.PropertyCount"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Property Count" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="4">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="3" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Addresses.Count}" /> <Run>addresses</Run>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
namespace Sandbox.Wpf.PropertyCount
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PropertyCount.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PropertyCount : Window
    {

        public PropertyCount()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new Model();
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public List<Person> People { get; private set; }

        public Model()
        {

            People = new List<Person>{
                new Person ("joe", new List<object> { 1, 2, 3 }),
                new Person ("bob", new List<object> { 1, 2 }),
                new Person ("kay", new List<object> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }),
                new Person ("jill", new List<object> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }),
            };
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<object> Addresses { get; set; }

        public Person(string name, List<object> addresses)
        {
            Name = name;
            Addresses = addresses;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Robert's answer got me really close to what I was after.  However, I'm adding many items to the list from a service call, and didn't want the event firing for each item.  To this end, I took advantage of functionality already built into `BindingList`:

```
public class BindingListNotifyCount<T> : BindingList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnListChanged(e);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Count");
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then I simply use it as:

```
displayItems.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
serviceItems.ForEach(item => displayItems.Add(item));
displayItems.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
displayItems.ResetBindings();
```

Comment: Your answer looks great. In your sample, please can you give a hint what type / element `displayItems` is please?

Comment: @Nasenbaer `displayItems` would be an instance of `BindingListNotifyCount<T>`.  I don't remember what the particular `T` was in the instance I used, but I believe it did also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.