# Bind a List's count to a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have the following Data class:

```
class CustomerProducts
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<ProductId> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And the following XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="grd_CustomerProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=CustomerOverview}" />
```

NB: `CustomerOverview` is an `ObservableCollection<CustomerProducts>` within the Main Window

I am looking to bind the `CustomerOverview` collection to a DataGrid such that you get the Customer ID and a Count of all the Id's in Products. e.g:

> Id........| Number Of Products
>
> 0001a  | 3
>
> bb032  | 0
>
> 3rt640 | 99

How can I change my XAML to achieve this, or do I need to implement something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916564/bind-to-count-of-items-in-the-datacontext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add columns manually with proper Binding:

```
<DataGrid Name="grd_CustomerProducts" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=CustomerOverview}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" 
                                        Binding="{Binding Id}" 
                                        />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" 
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=Products.Count}" 
                                        />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding column to DataGrid like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Products.Count}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```